# OpenXML c++/cli

Tags: ms-word, c++-cli, openxml, openxml-sdk, xdoc

I want to create a .docx document (Word 2007 and 2010)  with OpenXML in C++/CLI

I use this code for generate the document:

```
WordprocessingDocument^ wordDoc  = WordprocessingDocument::Create("C:\\...\MyFile.docx", WordprocessingDocumentType::Document);

MainDocumentPart^ mainPart = wordDoc->AddMainDocumentPart();

Document^ elt = gcnew Document( gcnew Body( gcnew Paragraph( gcnew Run( gcnew DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Wordprocessing::Text("Hello !") ) ) ) ); 

elt->Save(mainPart);

mainPart->Document->Save();

wordDoc->Close();
```

**The file is created but it is empty.**

If I write this code in C#, **the file is good and it contains the text**.

Why my code in C++/cli, create the file (MyFile.docx) with no text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I repro this problem.  Not sure what is going on, this syntax is documented to work.  It works properly when you write the code explicitly, using the AppendChild() method.  Like this:

```
WordprocessingDocument^ wordDoc  = WordprocessingDocument::Create("C:\\temp\\MyFile.docx", WordprocessingDocumentType::Document);
MainDocumentPart^ mainPart = wordDoc->AddMainDocumentPart();

mainPart->Document = gcnew Document;
Body^ body = mainPart->Document->AppendChild(gcnew Body);
Paragraph^ para = body->AppendChild(gcnew Paragraph);
Run^ run = para->AppendChild(gcnew Run);
run->AppendChild(gcnew DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Wordprocessing::Text("Hello !"));

delete wordDoc;
```

Comment: this code works ! I don't understand why the first code doesn't work. Thank you very much !